# Vectorize calculation across relational dataframes in R

Tags: r, for-loop, relational-database, vectorization

Is it possible in R to vectorize a calculation on data in a dataframe, where one criteria on which the calculation is performed comes from an external dataframe? This can be performed using a *for loop*, however it is slow.

The full task involves asking questions of 15 years of medical laboratory data in relational format. For example, what is the lowest haemoglobin level recorded for a patient in the three months following a surgical procedure? This from two tables: one with dates of surgery (~ 6000, often multiple per patient) and one of dated haemoglobin levels (~200,000, multiple per patient).  A loop as below takes ~30 minutes per query.

In this *MWE* data is in two tables and is linked by an index.

```
##create two dataframes
a<-c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID2","ID1")
b<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
c<-as.Date(c("2005-01-01","2002-01-01","2003-01-01","2004-01-01","2001-01-01"))
df.1<-cbind.data.frame(a,b,c,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

d<-c("ID1","ID2","ID1")
e<-as.Date(c("2002-02-01","2001-02-01","2000-01-01"))
df.2<-cbind.data.frame(d,e,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)        

>df.1
   a  b     c
1 ID1 1 2005-01-01
2 ID2 2 2002-01-01
3 ID3 3 2003-01-01
4 ID2 4 2004-01-01
5 ID1 5 2001-01-01
>df.2
   d       e
1 ID1 2002-02-01
2 ID2 2001-02-01
3 ID1 2000-01-01


out<-rep(NA,length(df.2$d))
for(i in 1:length(df.2$d)){
out[i]<-max(df.1$b[df.1$a==df.2$d[i] & df.1$c>df.2$e[i]])
}


> cbind(df.2,out)
   d      e       out
1 ID1 2002-02-01   1
2 ID2 2001-02-01   4
3 ID1 2000-01-01   5
```

Comment: This: `df.1$a==df.2$d[i]` test a single value against an entire column and so does the other half of that logical expression. The the result is used as a column index. This really makes no sense at all. So what is it that you are trying to accomplish. anyway?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can vectorize a calculation in r with `Vectorize`.

However, I'm not sure what "slow" means here. And there are probably better ways to accomplish your task, but I would rather read a word problem than code.

```
##create two dataframes
a<-c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID2","ID1")
b<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
c<-as.Date(c("2005-01-01","2002-01-01","2003-01-01","2004-01-01","2001-01-01"))
df.1<-cbind.data.frame(a,b,c,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

d<-c("ID1","ID2","ID1")
e<-as.Date(c("2002-02-01","2001-02-01","2000-01-01"))
df.2<-cbind.data.frame(d,e,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)        

f <- function(i)
  ## your code here
  max(df.1$b[df.1$a==df.2$d[i] & df.1$c>df.2$e[i]])
vf <- Vectorize(f)

vf(1:3)
# [1] 1 4 5
```

Comment: Despite its name, the only thing `Vectorize` does is create an implicit loop with `mapply`. It's not going to be any faster.

Comment: true.. I was going to comment on the benchmarks but with 3 rows, it's not going to matter

Comment: It you just vectorize nonsense, you have not improved the world.